# How to remove the space between two BoxLayouts in Kivy?

Tags: python, user-interface, interface, kivy, calculator

**I state that I have already read the answers of other users to this question but none of them helped me.** I'm trying to program a calculator in python with the **kivy GUI interface**,he problem is that i can't remove that **space highlighted** in red in the attached photo down here. I have already tried with: `size_hint: None,None` and `size:root.size[0], "5dp"` to scale the BoxLayouts but it doesn't worked

```
         [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1ZwF.png


  BoxLayoutExample:
<BoxLayoutExample>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        text: "0"
        font_size: "30dp"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        Button:
            text: "7"
            size_hint: .1, .3
        Button:
            text: "4"
            size_hint: .1, .3
        Button:
            text: "1"
            size_hint: .1, .3

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        Button:
            text: ","
            size_hint: .1, .3
        Button:
            text: "0"
            size_hint: .1, .3
        Button:
            text: "="
            size_hint: .1, .3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are setting `size_hint` of the Buttons relative to its parent `BoxLayout`. So in effect your BoxLayout's are taking up 1/3 of the available space (because there are three widgets in `BoxLayoutExample`.

Here is how to fix it:

```
<BoxLayoutExample>:
    orientation: "vertical"

    Label:
        text: "0"
        font_size: "30dp"
        size_hint: 1, .8

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size_hint: 1, .1
        Button:
            text: "7"
        Button:
            text: "4"
        Button:
            text: "1"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size_hint: 1, .1
        Button:
            text: ","
        Button:
            text: "0"
        Button:
            text: "="
```

Adjust the size of the `Label` and the `BoxLayout` accordingly